# using jquery to check if a button was clicked or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to check if a button was clicked or not using jquery.

this is my snippet in the javascript section of my code

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {

jQuery(':button').click(function () {
    if (this.id == 'click') {
        alert('this button was clicked');
    }
    else if (this.id == 'button2') {
        alert('Button 2 was clicked');
    }
});

};
```

this is the button I am using to test the function

```
<button id="click">save</button>
```

on clicking the button nothing happens. please kindly assist

Comment: `jQuery('button')`

Comment: So you are binding the event after it was clicked....

Comment: Why are you setting a click handler in `onbeforeunload`?  When that event is happening, isn't clicking a button pretty much out of the question thereafter?  What are you actually trying to accomplish here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following way:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery(':button').click(function () {
    if (this.id == 'click') {
        alert('this button was clicked');
    }
    else if (this.id == 'button2') {
        alert('Button 2 was clicked');
    }
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="click">save</button>
<button id="button2">button2</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

The Events triggered by the button are given on jQuery Code load so you need to place it in a $(document).ready()

This will work for you:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#click").click(function(){
        //do stuff
    });
})
```

here you directly adress the id of the button your html would look like:

```
<button id="click">save</button>
```

which is actually the same :D

Answer (score 0):

You are binding the event after it was clicked. When the onbeforeevent has already fired, the click has happened.

You need to bind it outside of that event.

```
jQuery(function(){

    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        console.log(clicked);
    };

    var clicked = null;
    jQuery('button').on("click", function () {
        clicked = this.id;
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var clickedButtons = [];
$('button').on('click', function(){
  if($.inArray($(this).attr('id'), clickedButtons){
    console.log('button allready clicked once');
  } else {
    clickdeButtons.push($(this).attr('id'));
  }
});
```

this solution can handle more than one button